# Rails form select_month helper with custom translation for months

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use custom month abbreviations in the select_month helper dropdown by using a translation.

My form looks like the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 pad-bottom">
  <div class="pull-right pad-top">
    <%= select_month(Date.today, :field_name => 'cc_exp_month', :add_month_numbers => true, :use_month_names => t('date.abbr_month_names')) %>
    <%= select_year(Date.today, :field_name => 'cc_exp_year', :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 8.years.from_now.year) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an `en.yml` file containing the following translation:

```
date:
  abbr_month_names: [~, M1, M2, M3, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

I have tried to use the following and they don't seem to help either.

```
:use_month_names => %w(t('date.abbr_month_names'))
:use_month_names => %w(I18n.t('date.abbr_month_names'))
```

Does anyone know how to do this by chance?

Comment: What is the delta between what your code is currently doing and the desired behavior?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I actually determine what my problem was. It was using the default en.yml value for that key so I just made a different key in my custom en.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the language as top level key of your translation file. In your case `en`. You can have a look into the default [rails locale file of active support](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml).

```
en:
  date:
    abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```